# Additional columns and item values in Woocommerce email order details

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, email-notifications

I am editing a Woocommerce email template but am a little stuck - I need to add a few columns to the order summary table so that it contains:

- Quantity
- Product
- Product code
- Price
- VAT

I have added the table headers that I need into 'email-order-details.php' (copied to my theme's email folder) to but not sure how to get the actual content into the table.  The code from the file is below:

```
<?php
/**
 * Order details table shown in emails.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-details.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version 3.3.1
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$text_align = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ); ?>

<h2>
    <?php
    if ( $sent_to_admin ) {
        $before = '<a class="link" href="' . esc_url( $order->get_edit_order_url() ) . '">';
        $after  = '</a>';
    } else {
        $before = '';
        $after  = '';
    }
    /* translators: %s: Order ID. */
    echo wp_kses_post( $before . sprintf( __( 'Order #%s', 'woocommerce' ) . $after . ' (<time datetime="%s">%s</time>)', $order->get_order_number(), $order->get_date_created()->format( 'c' ), wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ) );
    ?>
</h2>

<div style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
    <table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product code', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'VAT', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            echo wc_get_email_order_items( $order, array( // WPCS: XSS ok.
                'show_sku'      => $sent_to_admin,
                'show_image'    => false,
                'image_size'    => array( 32, 32 ),
                'plain_text'    => $plain_text,
                'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin,
            ) );
            ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <?php
            $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals();

            if ( $totals ) {
                $i = 0;
                foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
                    $i++;
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="4" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $total['label'] ); ?></th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $total['value'] ); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            if ( $order->get_customer_note() ) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="4" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Additional notes:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                    <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php echo wp_kses_post( wptexturize( $order->get_customer_note() ) ); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ); ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's the code of the product being ordered - it's available on the product page so I imagine is something that can be added here?

Comment: No it's a custom code that exists for each product that is included on the import sheet and the product page

Comment: oh - i suppose then it's a custom attribute that is associated with each product. is it possible to display one of those?

Comment: I can not guess what it is and how to display it… What is the meta key? check on wp_postmeta table for an existing product ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your question customized template code which have 5 columns instead of 3 by default:

1. Quantity
2. Product
3. Product code
4. Price
5. VAT

You need to override another template file too: `emails/email-order-items.php` like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Email Order Items
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-items.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version 3.5.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

$text_align = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) :
    $product       = $item->get_product();
    $sku           = '';
    $purchase_note = '';
    $image         = '';

    if ( ! apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_visible', true, $item ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    if ( is_object( $product ) ) {
        $sku           = $product->get_sku();
        $purchase_note = $product->get_purchase_note();
        $image         = $product->get_image( $image_size );
    }

    ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_class', 'order_item', $item, $order ) ); ?>">
        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
            <?php echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', $item->get_quantity(), $item ) ); ?>
        </td>
        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align: middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; word-wrap:break-word;">
        <?php

        // Show title/image etc.
        if ( $show_image ) {
            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail', $image, $item ) );
        }

        // Product name.
        echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $item->get_name(), $item, false ) );

        // SKU.
        if ( $show_sku && $sku ) {
            echo wp_kses_post( ' (#' . $sku . ')' );
        }

        // allow other plugins to add additional product information here.
        do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text );

        wc_display_item_meta( $item, array(
            'label_before' => '<strong class="wc-item-meta-label" style="float: left; margin-right: .25em; clear: both">',
        ) );

        // allow other plugins to add additional product information here.
        do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text );

        ?>
        </td>
        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
            <?php echo wp_kses_post( $sku ); ?>
        </td>
        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
            <?php echo wp_kses_post( wc_price( round( $item->get_subtotal(), wc_get_price_decimals() ) ) ); ?>
        </td>
        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
            <?php echo wp_kses_post( wc_price( round( $item->get_subtotal_tax(), wc_get_price_decimals() ) ) ); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php

    if ( $show_purchase_note && $purchase_note ) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
                <?php
                echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( do_shortcode( $purchase_note ) ) );
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then you will get something like:

[image]

**Note:** For the product code if it's some custom data, you will have to findout how to get it replacing:

```
<?php echo wp_kses_post( $sku ); ?>
```

by the correct value.

Comment: thanks very much - especially for your comments at the end. i have managed to change the template so that i have all the right cells but i can't get the 'price minus VAT' and 'VAT only' prices to display using your code?

Comment: @J4G Ok I have just edited/updated my code… So you have the price excluding vat now. My code perfectly works… why you took the code of  jaydeep. I don't catch.

Comment: thank you - although the prices still don't come up correctly for some reason! i get £0 for VAT and the total price for price, I'm not sure why

Comment: i just updated my site to the latest version but it's still not working. i'm not sure why, if you have any ideas it would be much appreciated but if not you've already got me much further along than i was!

Comment: I have updated the code again with last woocommerce version and template. I have tested again and it works.

Comment: it doesn't work for me, perhaps it's an error in my store set up but i can't see one

Comment: @J4G As you have accepted my answer: Does It worked then?

Comment: yes it did - thank you. the problem is how my products are set up

Answer (score 1):

You are going in the correct way. Now to Add the value field in Order Table, you have to add that  in Your-Theme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-items.php

In this file, you can add your  for the VAT like this.

```
<?php
/**
 * Email Order Items
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-items.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version 3.5.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

$text_align = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) :
    $product       = $item->get_product();
    $sku           = '';
    $purchase_note = '';
    $image         = '';

    if ( ! apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_visible', true, $item ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    if ( is_object( $product ) ) {
        $sku           = $product->get_sku();
        $purchase_note = $product->get_purchase_note();
        $image         = $product->get_image( $image_size );
    }

    ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_class', 'order_item', $item, $order ) ); ?>">
        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align: middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; word-wrap:break-word;">
        <?php

        // Show title/image etc.
        if ( $show_image ) {
            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail', $image, $item ) );
        }

        // Product name.
        echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $item->get_name(), $item, false ) );

        // SKU.
        if ( $show_sku && $sku ) {
            echo wp_kses_post( ' (#' . $sku . ')' );
        }

        // allow other plugins to add additional product information here.
        do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text );

        wc_display_item_meta( $item, array(
            'label_before' => '<strong class="wc-item-meta-label" style="float: left; margin-right: .25em; clear: both">',
        ) );

        // allow other plugins to add additional product information here.
        do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text );

        ?>
        </td>
        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
            <?php echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', $item->get_quantity(), $item ) ); ?>
        </td>
        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
            <?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ) ); ?>
        </td>

        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
            Vat Value Comes Here
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php

    if ( $show_purchase_note && $purchase_note ) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
                <?php
                echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( do_shortcode( $purchase_note ) ) );
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: thanks very much jaydeep - are you able to message me directly?

Comment: thanks very much. i have managed to change the template so that i have all the right cells but i can't get the 'price - VAT' and 'VAT only' prices to display?

Comment: loic - i used jaydeep's code to modify the email_order_items.php template however trying to use your code to display the price (which isn't working)